# Control CheckMark on start from a the listview : simple_list_item_single_choice

Tags: android, listview

> 1. I would like to keep the information of the checkmark, the way I was trying to do it is by controlling if a checkmark is true or false at the beginning.

I've tried putting all of them true by using setItemChecked(i,true) but it's not working...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Stigmate_P));
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

listView.setItemChecked(0,true);
listView.setItemChecked(1,true);
listView.setItemChecked(2,true);
```

> 2. When I'm using setOnItemClickListener, I would like to not change the state of my check mark. I've found a way to do so but I'm positive this isn't the best way.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
    if (Var[i] == 2){
        listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
    }
    else if (Var[i] == 1){
        listView.setItemChecked(i,false);

    }
}
```

Here is most of the java code for my listview

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int POSITION;
public static int Var[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

private Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
ListView listView;
ImageView ImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (POSITION == 0){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" ");}

    if (POSITION == 1){

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Stigmate");

        ImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.r_stigmate);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainMenu2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Stigmate_P));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        listView.setItemChecked(0,true);
        listView.setItemChecked(1,true);
        listView.setItemChecked(2,true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                if (Var[i] == 2){
                    listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
                }
                else if (Var[i] == 1){
                    listView.setItemChecked(i,false);
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("CountryName",listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                startActivity(intent);

                int n = 0;
                for (n= 0; n < 20 ; n++) {
                    if(i==n){
                        Main3Activity.POSITION3 = n;
                    }}
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int pos, long id) {
                if (Var[pos] == 1){
                    listView.setItemChecked(pos,true);
                    Var[pos] = 2;
                }
                else if (Var[pos] == 2){
                    listView.setItemChecked(pos,false);
                    Var[pos] = 1;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well, first you need set the adapter, then set check able items as checked.

please  check the note layout should be

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice not android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice

try below code

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int POSITION;
public static int Var[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};


private Toolbar mActionBarToolbar; 
ListView listView;
ImageView ImageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


if (POSITION == 0){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" ");}


if (POSITION == 1){

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Stigmate");


    ImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.r_stigmate);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainMenu2);


 // make note : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice not android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice 
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Stigmate_P));

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    // add this lines after you set the adapter 
    /*listView.setItemChecked(0,true);
    listView.setItemChecked(1,true);
    listView.setItemChecked(2,true);*/

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {

            if (Var[i] == 2){
                listView.setItemChecked(i,true);
            }
            else if (Var[i] == 1){
                listView.setItemChecked(i,false);

            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CountryName",listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            startActivity(intent);



            int n = 0;
            for (n= 0; n < 20 ; n++) {
                if(i==n){
                    Main3Activity.POSITION3 = n;
                }}

        }

    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {

            if (Var[pos] == 1){
                listView.setItemChecked(pos,true);
                Var[pos] = 2;
            }
            else if (Var[pos] == 2){
                listView.setItemChecked(pos,false);
                Var[pos] = 1;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

 // here you should set checked items 
    listView.setItemChecked(0,true);
    listView.setItemChecked(1,true);
    listView.setItemChecked(2,true);


}
```

Comment: Many Thanks, It's working perfectly fine. Also,
I'm using item_single_choice instead of item_multiple_choice just for the checkmark style

Comment: My pleasure. Can you accept the ans and upvote it please.

Comment: please think before you downvote something at least accepted answers